# use cmd "java -jar apktool.jar b D:\smali > nul" to get apk

Tags: apktool

I find the apk's `AndroidManifest.xml`,

```
platformBuildVersionCode="23" 
platformBuildVersionName="6.0-2438415"
```

not original

```
platformBuildVersionCode="26" 
platformBuildVersionName="8.0.0""
```

What's happen? why `apktool` can change `platformBuildVersionCode` and `platformBuildVersionName`? I don't know how to fix it.

original:
[image: original]

after:
[image: after]

Answer (score 0):

Apktool just runs the `aapt1`/`aapt2` binary at the end of the build procedure. This means you are re-running the code that sets those platform variables.

There is intended functionality right now.

That would require a change in Apktool at the aapt level, which would require modifying 3 platforms (unix/mac/win) for both aapt versions.

Comment: I don't understand how to change in Apktool at the aapt level,there I use the apktool versions is "apktool_2.3.3.jar" and the "aapt.exe" is belong to "sdk\build-tools\26.0.2".Please tell me how to do it?

Comment: You would need to build aapt from source using AOSP - https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/blob/master/INTERNAL.md#building-aapt-binaries